# PODs Failing to compile after xcode update

Tags: xcode

I just updated my xcode to Version 10.1 (10B61). After doing so, my pods don't work. See below error messages. Aside from PKHUD, the error messages don't provide suggestions as to how to fix this issue. Per online sources, I've updated  my OS to High Sierra 10.13.6. Any suggestions on how to get the app to compile? It was working before the update.

[image]

Comment: Xcode offers you the "Conversion to Swift 4.2", so this looks like a Swift 3 app? I would recommned upgrading it to 4.2 first, using Xcode 9 where Swift 3 is still supported, and then moving to Xcode 10/Swift 5 in a separate step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Xcode, select the Pods project and on the left panel select the frameworks that are causing the issue. On Build Settings, browse for Swift and make sure you have correctly set the version you have installed of those frameworks.

[image]

You can check that framework is fine after you tweak that value by compiling the framework after selecting it.

[image]

Just run cmd+B to compile and check if it build successfully. If you don't see the framework on the list just go to manage schemes and add it.